# enum decoder json data swift

Tags: swift

I try to decode json from api, for that i use this website : https://app.quicktype.io/

this is my json from api :

```
{
     "id":"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
     "uuid":"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
     "brand":"Nike",
     "breadcrumbs":[
        
     ],
     "browseVerticals":[
        "sneakers"
     ],
     "category":"Nike Dunk",
     "charityCondition":0,
     "childId":null,
     "colorway":"White/Black-Total Orange",
     "condition":"New",
     "countryOfManufacture":"VN",
     "dataType":"product",
     "description":"",
     "hidden":false,
     "listingType":"standard",
     "minimumBid":25,
     "gender":"men",
     "doppelgangers":[
        
     ],
     "media":{
        "imageUrl":"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=700&h=500&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        "smallImageUrl":"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=300&h=214&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        "thumbUrl":"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=140&h=100&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        "gallery":[
           
        ],
        "hidden":false
     },
     "name":"Black White (2021)",
     "productCategory":"sneakers",
     "releaseDate":"",
     "releaseTime":0,
     "belowRetail":false,
     "retailPrice":110,
     "shoe":"Nike Dunk High",
     "shortDescription":"Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021",
     "styleId":"DD1399-105",
     "tickerSymbol":"NK-NIDLFDXWB",
     "title":"Nike Dunk High Black White (2021)",
     "traits":[
        {
           "name":"Style",
           "value":"DD1399-105",
           "filterable":true,
           "visible":true,
           "highlight":true
        },
        {
           "name":"Colorway",
           "value":"White/Black-Total Orange",
           "filterable":true,
           "visible":true,
           "highlight":true
        },
        {
           "name":"Retail Price",
           "value":110,
           "filterable":true,
           "visible":true,
           "highlight":false
        },
        {
           "name":"Featured",
           "value":false,
           "filterable":false,
           "visible":false,
           "highlight":false
        }
     ],
     "type":0,
     "urlKey":"nike-dunk-high-black-white-total-orange-2021",
     "year":0,
     "shoeSize":null,
     "market":{
        "productId":0,
        "skuUuid":"",
        "productUuid":"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
        "lowestAsk":173,
        "lowestAskSize":"15",
        "parentLowestAsk":0,
        "numberOfAsks":196,
        "hasAsks":1,
        "salesThisPeriod":69,
        "salesLastPeriod":0,
        "highestBid":220,
        "highestBidSize":"9.5",
        "numberOfBids":230,
        "hasBids":1,
        "annualHigh":297,
        "annualLow":67,
        "deadstockRangeLow":238,
        "deadstockRangeHigh":274,
        "volatility":0.070391,
        "deadstockSold":5891,
        "pricePremium":1.627,
        "averageDeadstockPrice":175,
        "lastSale":256,
        "lastSaleSize":"10.5",
        "salesLast72Hours":69,
        "changeValue":51,
        "changePercentage":0.249544,
        "absChangePercentage":0.249544,
        "totalDollars":1029494,
        "lastLowestAskTime":1639141012,
        "lastHighestBidTime":1639160362,
        "lastSaleDate":"2021-12-11T00:55:16+00:00",
        "createdAt":"2021-06-29T04:46:03+00:00",
        "updatedAt":1639184839,
        "deadstockSoldRank":37,
        "pricePremiumRank":1,
        "averageDeadstockPriceRank":42,
        "featured":0
     },
     "_tags":[
        "sneakers",
        "nike",
        "nike",
        "dunk",
        "style_id|dd1399-105",
        "retail_price|110",
        "colorway|white/black-total orange"
     ],
     "lock_selling":false,
     "selling_countries":[
        "AD",
        "AE",
       
     ],
     "buying_countries":[
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "ES",
        "US",
        "XK",
        "IC",
        "IN"
     ],
     "objectID":"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255"
  }
```

this is my Preview Provider :

```
class DeveloperPreview {

static let instance = DeveloperPreview()
init() { }

let sneaker = Sneakers(
     id:"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
     uuid:"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
     brand:"Nike",
     breadcrumbs:[
        
     ],
     browseVerticals:[
        "sneakers"
     ],
     category:"Nike Dunk",
     charityCondition:0,
     childID: JSONNull(),
     colorway:"White/Black-Total Orange",
     condition:"New",
     countryOfManufacture:"VN",
     dataType:"product",
     welcomeDescription: "welcom",
     hidden:false,
     listingType:"standard",
     minimumBid:25,
     gender:"men",
     doppelgangers:[
        
     ],
     media: Media(
        imageURL:"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=700&h=500&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        smallImageURL:"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=300&h=214&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        thumbURL:"https://images.stockx.com/images/Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=140&h=100&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1624941957",
        gallery:[
           
        ],
        hidden:false

     ),
     name:"Black White (2021)",
     productCategory:"sneakers",
     releaseDate:"",
     releaseTime:0,
     belowRetail:false,
     retailPrice:110,
     shoe:"Nike Dunk High",
     shortDescription:"Nike-Dunk-Low-Black-White-2021",
     styleID:"DD1399-105",
     tickerSymbol:"NK-NIDLFDXWB",
     title:"Nike Dunk High Black White (2021)",
     traits: [traits],
     type:0,
     urlKey:"nike-dunk-high-black-white-total-orange-2021",
     year:0,
     shoeSize: JSONNull(),
     market: Market(
        productID:0,
        skuUUID:"",
        productUUID:"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255",
        lowestAsk:173,
        lowestAskSize:"15",
        parentLowestAsk:0,
        numberOfAsks:196,
        hasAsks:1,
        salesThisPeriod:69,
        salesLastPeriod:0,
        highestBid:220,
        highestBidSize:"9.5",
        numberOfBids:230,
        hasBids:1,
        annualHigh:297,
        annualLow:67,
        deadstockRangeLow:238,
        deadstockRangeHigh:274,
        volatility:0.070391,
        deadstockSold:5891,
        pricePremium:1.627,
        averageDeadstockPrice:175,
        lastSale:256,
        lastSaleSize:"10.5",
        salesLast72Hours:69,
        changeValue:51,
        changePercentage:0.249544,
        absChangePercentage:0.249544,
        totalDollars:1029494,
        lastLowestAskTime:1639141012,
        lastHighestBidTime:1639160362,
        lastSaleDate:"2021-12-11T00:55:16+00:00",
        createdAt:"2021-06-29T04:46:03+00:00",
        updatedAt:1639184839,
        deadstockSoldRank:37,
        pricePremiumRank:1,
        averageDeadstockPriceRank:42,
        featured:0
     ),
     tags:[
        "sneakers",
        "nike",
        "nike",
        "dunk",
        "style_id|dd1399-105",
        "retail_price|110",
        "colorway|white/black-total orange"
     ],
     lockSelling:false,
     sellingCountries:[
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "US",
        "IN"
     ],
     buyingCountries:[
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "IN"
     ],
     objectID:"7d37091c-f214-491a-a50c-d289f0f7e255"
)

let traits = Trait(
   name:"Style",
   value: .bool(true),
   filterable:true,
   visible:true,
   highlight:true
)
```

and this is my decoder :

```
struct Trait: Codable {
    let name: String
    let value: Value
    let filterable, visible, highlight: Bool
}

enum Value: Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Value.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Value"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .bool(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

My error come from the preview provider :

"Cannot use instance member 'traits' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6ruR.png)

Comment: You are trying to initialize trait with itself. It should be `traits: [Trait]` which mean traits is an array of type `Trait`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is exactly pointed out by compiler.
Converting from API response, this should work as expected on error snippet.

```swift
 traits: [
          Trait(
           name:"Style",
           value: .string("DD1399-105"),
           filterable:true,
           visible:true,
           highlight:true
          ),
          Trait(
           name:"Colorway",
           value: .string("White/Black-Total Orange"),
           filterable:true,
           visible:true,
           highlight:true
          ),
          Trait(
           name:"Retail Price",
           value: .integer(110),
           filterable:true,
           visible:true,
           highlight:false
          ),
          Trait(
           name:"Featured",
           value: .bool(false),
           filterable:false,
           visible:false,
           highlight:false
          )
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize properties which depend on each other on the top level of a class, you have to create the trait inside `let sneaker = Sneakers( ...`

Replace

```
traits: [traits],
```

with

```
 traits: [Trait(
      name:"Style",
      value: .bool(true),
      filterable:true,
      visible:true,
      highlight:true)],
```